# How to make ToggleButton and ImageButton to be the same height in RealtiveLayout?

Tags: android, layout, button, alignment, togglebutton

I have a `RelativeLayout` with one `ImageButton`, one `ToggleButton` and some other controls. Both buttons aligned on the right of the RelativeLayout. I want them to have the same height. Here is my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/copy"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:textOn="Hide"
        android:textOff="View" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageButton" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageButton" />

    <!-- ... other controls ... -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to set `layout_height="0dip"` and used `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` to make ToggleButton to have the same height as ImageButton, but this doesn't work:

[image]

As you see, ToggleButton aligned incorrectly, it's always little higher than ImageButton. What am I doing wrong?

*Testing on Android 2.3*

Comment: so don't use the "wrap_content".. when you use it, the button will be in the dimensions of it's content that he contains.. so i'll suggest you to set the buttons height and width by yourself..

Comment: do you have this issue in the Graphical Layout editor ? is it only on android 2.3 or on other versions as well ?

Comment: @fiddler No problems in my Graphical Layout (I use the latest target SDK), and no problems in Android 4.x, I still did not tested on Android 3.x, the problem seems appearing only on 2.x

Comment: @Janmejoy No chance to use automatic height? :(

Comment: @Andrew why it is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this..

```
         <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonView"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"
        android:textOff="View"
        android:textOn="Hide" />

    <!-- ... other controls ... -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Toggle button will be little bit more height than compare to image button you have to increase the width and height for the image button than it will be perfect ,using same width and height little difference you can find

[image]

Comment: Seems your solution is the most appropriate. However, I'll need to provide 2 different layouts, for Android 2.3 and for Android 4.x. I'll wait for 1-2 days and then will accept your answer. Maybe someone else will find a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_height="150dp"//some height
    ...

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonView"
    android:layout_height="150dp"//same height as above
```

Comment: Not worked for me. The visual height of ToggleButton is still 2 pixels more than ImageButton on Android 2.3

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a horizontal `LinearLayout` as a child of the `RelativeLayout` and add the `ToggleButton` and
   `ImageView` to it.
2. For the `ToggleButton` set `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

**Edit:**
Here's the working code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textOff="View"
            android:textOn="Hide" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/copy" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit2:**

Understood your problem. The above code *appears* to work only on Android 4.0, with the default Holo theme.

On Android 2.3, in the default theme, the style of `ImageButton` specifies the background as [`btn_default_normal`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_normal.9.png), in which the top row of pixels is transparent. Whereas the `ToggleButton`'s background for the same theme uses [`btn_default_small_normal`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_small_normal.9.png), which has opaque pixels on the top row. (Click on the links to check for yourself.)

Hence, when placed alongside a `ToggleButton`, they don't *appear* to have the same height.

Comment: I tried your solution with LinearLayout - no effect. I have tested with  `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on ToggleButton

Comment: @Andrew Strange, I just tried it and it worked. Edited my answer with the working code.

Comment: You testing on Android 2.3?

Comment: Now I understand. Any ideas how to make them look like having same height? Maybe I can override that theme settings somewhow?